# Error en función: Unexpected token }

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una funcion JavaScript dentro de un archivo JS

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://swapi.co/api/people/1/?format=json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(json) {
      //console.log(json.name);
      $("h2.name").text(json.name);
    }
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(per) {
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        var a = $("<div onclick='data2('ddddd')' class='col-md-4'>" + per.results[i].name + "</div>");
        $(".row").append(a);
        //console.log(per.results[i].name);
      }
    }
  });
});

function data2(nom) {
  console.log(nom);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Accueil</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Start Wars</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nous</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<!--images banner-->
<div class="text-center">
  <img src="images/stw.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
</div>

<div class="alert alert-dark text-center" role="alert">
  <h2 class="name mb-0">Loading...</h2>
</div>

<div class="row">

</div>

</div>
```

Quiero que la función `data2` se ejecute cada vez que se ejecute al hacer click en los `div` que se crean con jQuery. Pero al hacer click me marca este error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

en la línea de la función `data2`.

Comment: Sin hacer ningún cambio en tu código, lo he puesto como ejecutable y he añadido jQuery. Si le das al botón de "Ejecutar" verás que no falla nada. Esto se debe a que hay más en tu problema que sólo el JS, también deberías incluir el HTML relacionado para que podamos reproducir el problema.

Comment: ya lo agregué el HTML

Comment: Gracias. Lo he puesto como parte del ejecutable y ahora ya se puede ver el problema (he comentado los console.log para que no añadan ruido)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en las comillas de esta línea:

```
var a = $("<div onclick='data2('ddddd')' class='col-md-4'>" + per.results[i].name + "</div>");
```

En concreto, en la parte del `onclick`. Si te fijas, el `onclick` se abre con comillas simples `'` que también se usan para la cadena de texto que se pasa a `data2`. Una solución sería cambiar las comillas simples de apertura y cierre por unas comillas dobles escapadas `\"` y ya funcionaría:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://swapi.co/api/people/1/?format=json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(json) {
      //console.log(json.name);
      $("h2.name").text(json.name);
    }
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(per) {
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        var a = $("<div onclick=\"data2('ddddd')\" class='col-md-4'>" + per.results[i].name + "</div>");
        $(".row").append(a);
        //console.log(per.results[i].name);
      }
    }
  });
});

function data2(nom) {
  console.log(nom);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Accueil</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Start Wars</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nous</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<!--images banner-->
<div class="text-center">
  <img src="images/stw.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
</div>

<div class="alert alert-dark text-center" role="alert">
  <h2 class="name mb-0">Loading...</h2>
</div>

<div class="row">

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Aunque deberías plantearte  evitar el JS inline en el HTML. Sería mejor que crearas los eventos JS dentro del propio JavaScript con `addEventListener` o usando jQuery (ya que lo tienes en el proyecto).

Comment: como seria con el add event listener?